# How to search two different fields in redis search with an OR?

Tags: redis

I am trying to search `redisData` for when id1=1 or when id2=2.

```
FT.SEARCH 'idx:redisData' '@id1:{1} | @id2:{2}'
```

This is an invalid syntax

```
FT.SEARCH 'idx:redisData' '@id1:{1} or @id2:{2}'
```

and this does not seem to be working.   How can I run this search?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DIALECT 2

```
FT.SEARCH 'idx:redisData' '@id1:{1} | @id2:{2}' DIALECT 2
```